# Use Selenium to click a 'Load More Reviews' button (NOT WORKING only on chromedriver )

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to load more reviews using the right XPATH for the button but it always fails on chromedriver.

Also when i click on Load More Reviews on Google chrome or Opera, the new reviews appears but in chromedriver tehy do not, always the same first reviews no matter how much time i click on the button using the click or the cursor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.